# python binding of variable to particular expression

Tags: python, binding

I am developing a simple application which hava a file Constants.py containing all configuration, it is like this

```
x = y
```

during execution of program , the value of y changes , I want value of x o get updated too , automatically, this can be reffered as binding, how can I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python variable names point at values. `x=y` tells Python that the variable name `x` should point at the value that `y` is currently pointing at.

When you change `y`, then the variable name `y` points at a new value, while the variable name `x` still points at the old value.

You can not achieve what you want with plain variable names.

I like KennyTM's suggestion to define `x` as a function since it makes explicit that the value of `x` requires running some code (the lookup of the value of y).

However, if you want to maintain a uniform syntax (making all the constants accessible in the same way), then you could use a class with properties (attributes which call getter and setter functions):

Constants.py:

```
class BunchOConstants(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.y
    @x.setter
    def x(self,val):
        self.y=val
const=BunchOConstants(y=10,z='foo')
```

Your script.py:

```
import Constants

const=Constants.const
print(const.y)
# 10
print(const.x)
# 10
```

Here you change the "constant" y:

```
const.y='bar'
```

And the "constant" x is changed too:

```
print(const.x)
# bar
```

You can change `x` also,

```
const.x='foo'
```

and `y` too gets changed:

```
print(const.y)
# foo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the value (object) itself, then all references to it will be updated:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a  # b refers to the same object a is refering right now
>>> a.append('foo')
>>> print b
['foo']
```

However, if you make the name point to some other object, then other names will still reference whatever they were referencing before:

```
>>> a = 15
>>> print b
['foo']
```

That's how python works. Names are just references to objects. You can make a name reference the same object another name is referencing, but you can't make a name reference another name. Name attribution using the `=` operator (`a = 15`) changes what `a` refers to, so it can't affect other names.

Answer (score 0):

if your configuration values are inside a class, you could do something like this:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     a = 4
...     @property
...     def b(self):
...         return self.a
...
```

then, every time you access b, it will return the value of a.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution you can do. Just define a property and ask for the `fget` value you defined.

For example:

```
a = 7

@property 
def b():
    return a
```

if you ask for b, you will get something like this `<property object at 0x1150418>` but if you do `b.fget()`, you will obtain the value 7

Now try this:

```
a = 9
b.fget()  # this will give you 9. The current value of a
```

You don't need to have a class with this way, otherwise, I think you will need it.